# XMl to JSON through java pojo using jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I am trying to convert xml to json. First I created java class using the following xml

```
<CompositeResponse>
   <CompositeIndividualResponse>
      <PersonIdentification>2222</PersonIdentification>
   </CompositeIndividualResponse>
</CompositeResponse>
```

The following java classes are following:

```
public class Main {
    public CompositeResponse CompositeResponse;
    public CompositeResponse getCompositeResponse() {
        return CompositeResponse;
    }
    public void setCompositeResponse(CompositeResponse CompositeResponse) {
        this.CompositeResponse = CompositeResponse;
    }
}

public class CompositeResponse {
    private List<CompositeIndividualResponse> CompositeIndividualResponse;

public List<CompositeIndividualResponse> getCompositeIndividualResponse() {
    return CompositeIndividualResponse;
}
public void setCompositeIndividualResponse(List<CompositeIndividualResponse> CompositeIndividualResponse) {
    CompositeIndividualResponse = CompositeIndividualResponse;
}
}

public class CompositeIndividualResponse {

    private String Persondentification;

    public String getPersondentification() {
        return Persondentification;
    }
    public void setPersonIdentification (String PersonIdentification) {
      this.PersonIdentification = PersonIdentification; 
    }

}

I am using the following code for conversion: 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class XMLToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml")));
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        Main poppy = xmlMapper.readValue(content, Main.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(poppy);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following exception that CompositeIndividualResponse is not recognized.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "CompositeIndividualResponse" (class com.test.custom.copy.Main), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "CompositeResponse", "compositeResponse"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.test.custom.copy.Main["CompositeIndividualResponse"])
```

I believe my java pojo is not fit with xml data. So how to define collection of pojo to solve this problem so I can get the following json:

```
{  
   "CompositeResponse":{       
      "CompositeIndividualResponse":
      [  
         {  
            "PersonSSNIdentification":"221212501"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I do not need the Main.java class. Also I need to add jackson annotation to define xml element. The working code is following.

```
CompositeResponse.java

    public class CompositeResponse {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CompositeIndividualResponse")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "CompositeIndividualResponse",useWrapping = false)
        private List<CompositeIndividualResponse> compositeIndividualResponse;

        public List<CompositeIndividualResponse> getCompositeIndividualResponse() {
             return compositeIndividualResponse;
        }

       public void setCompositeIndividualResponse(List<CompositeIndividualResponse> compositeIndividualResponse) {
           this.compositeIndividualResponse = compositeIndividualResponse;
        }

    }

CompositeIndividualResponse.java: 

    public class CompositeIndividualResponse {

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PersonIdentification")
            private String personIdentification;

            public String getPersonIdentification() {
                return personIdentification;
            }
            public void setPersonIdentification (String personIdentification) {
              this.personIdentification= personIdentification; 
            }
    }

XMLToJson.java

    public class XMLToJson {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml")));
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            CompositeResponse poppy = xmlMapper.readValue(content, CompositeResponse.class);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(poppy);
            System.out.println(json);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define you POJO like this,

```
public class CompositeResponse {
     private List<CompositeIndividualResponse> compositeIndividualResponse;

     public List<CompositeIndividualResponse> getCompositeIndividualResponse() {
          return compositeIndividualResponse;
     }

    public void setCompositeIndividualResponse(List<CompositeIndividualResponse> compositeIndividualResponse) {
         CompositeIndividualResponse = compositeIndividualResponse;
     }
}

public class CompositeIndividualResponse {
    private String personIdentification;

    public String getPersonIdentification() {
        return personIdentification;
    }
    public void setPersonIdentification (String personIdentification) {
      this.personIdentification= personIdentification; 
    }
}
```

Then update your main program as below,

```
public class XMLToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml")));
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        CompositeResponse poppy = xmlMapper.readValue(content, CompositeResponse.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(poppy);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I donot need Main.Java. But I need to define Jackson annotation to make things done. 
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CompositeIndividualResponse") @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "CompositeIndividualResponse",useWrapping = false)
compositeIndividualResponse
Also for personIdentification i need to add the following annotation
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PersonIdentification")
personIdentification

Comment: Can you please see my answer and if it is good please upvote for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in field naming, all fields by default starts with small letter.
for example: `compositeResponse`

To avoid this problem add annotation `@JsonProperty` for each field, like this:

```
    @JsonProperty("persondentification")
    private String Persondentification;
```

Comment: Actually it is not the case. I donot need to main.java class here. Moreover I need to Jackson annotation to properly map xml to POJO. Please see my comment below. Thanks